# Movable Song of the Day on Shabbat

Tags: tefilla, shabbat

From what I have seen by attending services as well as viewing various Siddurim, it seems that on weekdays, the Song of the Day is said at the end of Shacharit (Nusach Ashkenaz after *Aleinu*; Nusach Sefard before it.)

However, on Shabbat and Yom Tov, I have seen it placed in one of 3 places for both Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard:

- Beginning of service just before start of *Psukei Dezimra*
- Just after Chazzan's Shacharit Amida repetition
- End of Musaf service either before or after *Shir Hakvod* or *Aleinu* (Shir Hakavod is also "portable".)

Why is there this flexibility on Shabbat / Yom Tov but not during the weekday?

Speculation: It's either the day itself or the fact that we say Musaph that creates the ambiguity.

Comment: What is the analogous weekday part to "after Musaf"? The only option which is different from the weekday is the before Psukei Dizimra one which is quite rare to see. I don't see much evidence for much more flexibility on Shabbat if any

Comment: You also get this on Rosh Hodesh and Hol HaMoed. Most Nusah Sefard places will say it before Keriat HaTorah.

Comment: @JoelK I haven't seen this. Then, again, I don't attend Nusach Sefard that often. I guess my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @DoubleAA Agree. But, there is one option still there, namely, at the beginning. I don't know anyone doing this on weekdays, but, my shul, e.g., does it at the beginning on Shabbat & Yom Tov.

Comment: According to Minhag Anglia, it is always recited before Baruch Sheamar, although it's always printed at the end of shacharit.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt If you can link a source, perhaps there is something there that hints to why they follow this rule. It may provide a clue as to why others put it at the end or what's special about Shabbat, or, perhaps, Musaph is the impetus that creates the ambiguity.

Comment: The source I have is the original (non-Koren) Sacks Siddur, which doesn't give a rationale for the hanhagah

Comment: It's a bit strange, but [here it says](https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-09-26_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf) that the recitation of the whole psalm comes from the אר"י

Comment: @Kazibácsi As much as I like "beurei", it has one main fault in that they don't index their "supplemental" articles, such as the one you found. I have to read it more thoroughly, as I think a citation there does imply a need to say it at the end of Shacharit.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt "the original (non-Koren) Sacks Siddur": isn't that just the updated version of the Singer _sidur_? Perhaps then the original Singer _sidur_ explains?

Comment: @msh210, the original Singer Siddur has no commentary and relatively limited instructions. I haven't seen R' Lord Jakobovitz's edition, but that's the only edition with commentary I currently have access to.